# Spring mongodb @DBRef on itself

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security

is it possible to add a `@DBRef` to a list which make a reference to himself. I think a example can explain my question:

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {
    @Indexed(unique = true, direction = IndexDirection.DESCENDING, dropDups = true)
    private final String uname;

    ...

    @DBRef 
    private  List<User>  contacts; // <-- The Problem

    ... (Getter / Setters, etc.)

}
```

If I run the code the console give me the error:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" ...
```

Is it possible to fix my code or do I have to create a new Document for the reference?

**EDIT:**

I have a strange problem now. For testing I out commented the `contacts` variable in the user class.

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private final   String      uid;

    @Indexed(unique = true, direction = IndexDirection.DESCENDING, dropDups = true)
    private final   String      uname;

    ...

    //private  List<String>  contacts;

    @DBRef private  Role        role;

    ...

}
```

But the error shows:

```
duplicate key error index: test.user.$contacts.uname  dup key: { : null }" , "code" : 11000}
```

Where comes the `$contacts.uname` from if the contacts list is out commented? I already restart the mongodb server and delete my collections.